# Join three tables in MySQL while putting records with the same date on the same row

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL database with three tables: `products`, `stock_updates` and `order_items`. I need to retrieve all products that have records in the `stock_updates` and/or `order_items` tables, while combining the rows with a registration/order on the same day (leaving time out of the scope).

##### Tables

Some example data in the three tables:

**`products`**

```
id | name
---|----------
1  | Product A
```

**`stock_updates`**

```
id | product_id | registered_at
---|------------|--------------------
1  | 1          | 2021-05-01 10:15:30
2  | 1          | 2021-05-15 20:30:45
```

**`order_items`**

```
id | product_id | ordered_at
---|------------|--------------------
1  | 1          | 2021-05-15 15:23:00
2  | 1          | 2021-06-01 12:34:56
```

##### Expected Result

```
product_id | registered_at       | ordered_at
-----------|---------------------|--------------------
1          | 2021-05-01 10:15:30 | NULL
1          | 2021-05-15 20:30:45 | 2021-05-15 15:23:00
1          | NULL                | 2021-06-01 12:34:56
```

##### My attempt

My best try so far (and came pretty close in my opinion):

```mysql
SELECT p.id, registered_at, ordered_at
FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN stock_updates AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN order_items AS o ON o.product_id = p.id
        AND (DATE(o.ordered_at) = DATE(s.registered_at) OR s.registered_at IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.id, DATE(s.registered_at), DATE(o.ordered_at)
```

This gives the following result:

```
id | registered_at       | ordered_at
---|---------------------|--------------------
1  | 2021-05-01 10:15:30 | NULL
1  | 2021-05-15 20:30:45 | 2021-05-15 15:23:00
```

So I'm only missing the case where the `registered_at` row is not filled.

Any suggestions for me to get this done?

---

Of course I have searched on the internet for this case, but did not find any answer that fits my problem.

Comment: try wrappying `o.product_id = p.id
        AND (DATE(o.ordered_at) = DATE(s.registered_at) OR s.registered_at IS NULL)` in parenthesis () , since these are all conditions that apply to the second join, correct?

Comment: What if for the same product there are 2 rows with the same date of registered_at and 2 rows with the same date of ordered_at? How would they be combined?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Just tried, no different result.

Comment: @forpas Then only one record should be used for that date (because of the `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.* FROM ( 
SELECT p.id, registered_at, ordered_at FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN stock_updates AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN order_items AS o ON o.product_id = p.id and  (DATE(o.ordered_at) = DATE(s.registered_at) OR s.registered_at IS NULL) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.id, registered_at, ordered_at FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN order_items AS o ON o.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN stock_updates AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
        AND (DATE(o.ordered_at) = DATE(s.registered_at) OR s.registered_at IS NULL)       
        GROUP BY p.id, DATE(s.registered_at), DATE(o.ordered_at) ) X
```

Comment: This one does the job. Even with more advanced queries and extra joins. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this query

Note : Please forget performance !

```
SELECT products.id, registered_at, ordered_at  FROM 
products 
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT order_items.product_id ordproductid, stock_updates.product_id stkproductid, order_items.ordered_at, stock_updates.registered_at FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(ordered_at) dt FROM order_items
            UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT DATE(registered_at) dt FROM stock_updates) datetbl
        
            LEFT JOIN order_items ON datetbl.dt = DATE(order_items.ordered_at)
            LEFT JOIN stock_updates ON datetbl.dt = DATE(stock_updates.registered_at)
    ) dates ON (dates.ordproductid = products.id OR dates.stkproductid = products.id)
    ORDER BY products.id, COALESCE(registered_at, ordered_at)
```

**Explanation**

Take a unified list of all possible dates from both the table and make it as the main derived table

```
(SELECT DISTINCT DATE(ordered_at) dt FROM order_items
            UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT DATE(registered_at) dt FROM stock_updates) datetbl
```

Then join the tables one by one!

Ideally, I would take order and stock records separately and build final out put in application layer.